# Is nonce claim supported in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to pass some value through AAD url.
For that purpose, we should be able to use nonce claim which will show the value passed in querystring parameter similar to adb2c.
But it is not working
url used:
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token?nonce=testValue
flow used:
client credentials flow

Answer (score 0):

**Yes the nonce claim can be obtained in Azure Active Directory :**

For the app registration created and the app details being noted:

[image]

***I have checked with following Authorization URL to get the nonce claim in the token***

example:

---

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/fb1xxxxf3a0c218f3b0/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id= xxx
&client_secret=NF88Qxxx
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
&nonce=12345
```

---

With this auth url , after the user is logged in with **`response_type =code+id_token`** or **`response_type =id_token`**

Login using correct account details of the app:

[image]

I could get the nonce claim that matches the url which I have given:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "-KI3Q9nNR7bRofxmeZoXqbHZGew"
}.{
  "aud": "xx",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx62-f3a0c218f3b0/v2.0",
  "iat": 1xx7,
  "nbf": xxx,
  "exp": 167xxx6,
  "aio": "ATQAy/xxx",
  "nonce": "12345",
  "rh": "0.xxx_AKQ.",
  "sub": "VsYxxxApY",
  "tid": "xx",
  "uti": "xx",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

[image]

test 2: with nonce=mynonce:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/fbxxx62-xxx3b0/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xx4f4-1e6fbd2ed06e&client_secret= txxO6cLC&response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access&nonce=mynonce
```

Nonce obtained in the token:

[image]